# Android - How to align text spaces in textView

Tags: android, textview

Example:

```
C1 =
DC =

TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);
tv.setText("C1 =\nDC =");
```

Both `C1` and `DC` is a text containing 2 characters with one space but still the "=" signs are not aligned vertically. Is there any code to make this happen? I Figured that since the width of Character "C" is slightly higher than the width of character "1" which makes spacing a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you have to change the font style of your TextView to be a mono-spaced type. I would recommend Droid Sans Mono

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :-

tv.setText("C1 = "+\n +DC = ");

Use this to gives space "\u0020" between them.
Tell me the result after you apply.

Comment: What is the difference between typing a regular space in textView and the \u0020 unicode? Because when I applied that.. I still have the same problem... But it was solved with the monospace typeface...